# edit mode for rigged character changes location

Tags: rigging, edit-mode, pose-mode

I have attached screenshots of my character in object mode in both pose position and rest position. Rest position causes it to move to a new location and rotate 90 degrees. the third photo is of my character in edit mode. Edit mode makes the character go to the rest position. I want to be able to edit my character mesh in-place or at least without it rotating 90 degress. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't see any screenshots? But you can edit from the pose position of your mesh by enabling `On Cage` and `Edit Mode` in the armature modifier on the modifiers panel.

Comment: holy crap finally, thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome.